# Is it possible open a url generated by window.webkitURL.createObjectURL in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, safari

I am trying open a Blob in Safari but when I click the link it takes me to the page that says that it can't open a url starting with "blob:". The following code works in FireFox, but I would like it work on Safari too.

```
function showBinary(rBody, rTitle)
{
  var blob = dataURItoBlob(rBody);
  var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var objURL = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
  var anchor = ['<a href="', objURL, '">', rTitle, '</a>']
  anchor = anchor.join('');
  document.write(anchor);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Safari won't open blob: URLs now, but depending on the data type you might try using a data: URL like:

```
var dataURL = "data:image/png,"+encodeURIComponent( window.btoa(rBody) );
var anchor = ['<a href="', dataURL, '">', rTitle, '</a>'];
```